# Ckeditor makes page unresponsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, ckeditor, tailwind-css

I have imported ckeditor to my project, and everything was responsive, but when I added ckeditor into my html the page went unresponsive for an unknown reason. When I go below about 660px then ckeditor and the whole form overflows.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ckeditor-responsiveness-30zbr?resolutionWidth=478&resolutionHeight=675) is a link to the codesandbox I created.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex felx-col place-items-center"> <--- grid replace flex flex-col
      <form className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow px-4 py-2 mx-2 sm:mx-0 max-w-2xl w-full">
```